# How to solve bail out error in Unix script invoking nawk?

Tags: shell, unix, awk

The following command is working fine when I am not writing it in a script file, but when I put this command in a script file, it shows an error.

```
nawk 'c-- >0;$0~s{if(b)for(c=b+1;c >1;c--)print r[(NR-c+1)%b];print;c=a}b{r[NR%b]=$0}' b=10 a=10 s="string pattern" file
```

The error is:

```
nawk: syntax error at source line 1 context is >>> ' <<< missing }
nawk: bailing out at source line 1
```

---

One of the comment responses to one of the many requests for 'What does your script look like' is:

```
#!/bin/ksh
Stringname=$1
directory=$2
d=$3
Command="nawk 'c-- >0;$0~s{if(b)for(c=b+1;c >1;c--)print r[(NR-c+1)%b];print;c=a}b{r[NR%b]=$0}' b=10 a=10 s=\"$stringname\" $directory"
$Command> $d
```

Storing the whole command in a string like that is hugely fraught; don't do it!  It's unnecessary and very, very hard to get right.

```
#!/bin/ksh
Stringname=$1
directory=$2
d=$3
nawk 'c-- >0;$0~s{if(b)for(c=b+1;c >1;c--)print r[(NR-c+1)%b];print;c=a}b{r[NR%b]=$0}' b=10 a=10 s="$stringname" $directory > $d
```

Comment: If it is a script file, there is absolutely no need to cram it all onto one line.  I can't work out what the code is supposed to be up to.  You could use the `-v b=10` notation for setting variables, though GNU `awk` is OK with your notation.  Do you get any insight when you run: `sh -x script` where `script` is the file containing that script?

Comment: @jonathan : i wrote this to print above 10 and below 10 lines from matched pattern string, could you please solve this problem.

Comment: I'd install GNU `grep` and use `grep -B 10 -A 10 "string pattern" file`.

Comment: Which shell do you use?  What's `$SHELL` set to?  Do you have a shebang at the top of the script file (that's `#!/bin/sh` or something similar as the first line)?  What happens if you run `$SHELL -x script`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quickest way to solve the problem of printing N lines before and M lines after a match is to install GNU `grep` and use:

```
grep -B $N -A $M 'string pattern' file
```

Failing that, here's a Perl script I about 5 years ago to do the job.  Note that there are some complications if you ask for 10 lines before and 10 lines after a match, and you have:

- a match at line 7 (not 10 lines before)
- a match at line 30 and another at 35 (need to print lines 20-45)
- a match at line 60 where the last line is line 65 (not 10 lines after)
- and there are multiple files to process.

This code does handle all that.  It can probably be improved.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
#
# @(#)$Id: sgrep.pl,v 1.6 2007/09/18 22:55:20 jleffler Exp $
#
# Perl-based SGREP (special grep) command
# 
# Print lines around the line that matches (by default, 3 before and 3 after).
# By default, include file names if more than one file to search.
#
# Options:
# -b n1     Print n1 lines before match
# -f n2     Print n2 lines following match
# -n        Print line numbers
# -h        Do not print file names
# -H        Do     print file names

use strict;
use constant debug => 0;
use Getopt::Std;
my(%opts);

sub usage
{
    print STDERR "Usage: $0 [-hnH] [-b n1] [-f n2] pattern [file ...]\n";
    exit 1;
}

usage unless getopts('hnf:b:H', \%opts);
usage unless @ARGV >= 1;

if ($opts{h} && $opts{H})
{
    print STDERR "$0: mutually exclusive options -h and -H specified\n";
    exit 1;
}

my $op = shift;

print "# regex = $op\n" if debug;

# print file names if -h omitted and more than one argument
$opts{F} = (defined $opts{H} || (!defined $opts{h} and scalar @ARGV > 1)) ? 1 : 0;
$opts{n} = 0 unless defined $opts{n};

my $before = (defined $opts{b}) ? $opts{b} + 0 : 3;
my $after  = (defined $opts{f}) ? $opts{f} + 0 : 3;

print "# before = $before; after = $after\n" if debug;

my @lines = (); # Accumulated lines
my $tail  = 0;  # Line number of last line in list
my $tbp_1 = 0;  # First line to be printed
my $tbp_2 = 0;  # Last line to be printed

# Print lines from @lines in the range $tbp_1 .. $tbp_2,
# leaving $leave lines in the array for future use.
sub print_leaving
{
    my ($leave) = @_;
    while (scalar(@lines) > $leave)
    {
        my $line = shift @lines;
        my $curr = $tail - scalar(@lines);
        if ($tbp_1 <= $curr && $curr <= $tbp_2)
        {
            print "$ARGV:" if $opts{F};
            print "$curr:" if $opts{n};
            print $line;
        }
    }
}

# General logic:
# Accumulate each line at end of @lines.
# ** If current line matches, record range that needs printing
# ** When the line array contains enough lines, pop line off front and,
#    if it needs printing, print it.
# At end of file, empty line array, printing requisite accumulated lines.

while (<>)
{
    # Add this line to the accumulated lines
    push @lines, $_;
    $tail = $.;

    printf "# array: N = %d, last = $tail: %s", scalar(@lines), $_ if debug > 1;

    if (m/$op/o)
    {
        # This line matches - set range to be printed
        my $lo = $. - $before;
        $tbp_1 = $lo if ($lo > $tbp_2);
        $tbp_2 = $. + $after;
        print "# $. MATCH: print range $tbp_1 .. $tbp_2\n" if debug;
    }

    # Print out any accumulated lines that need printing
    # Leave $before lines in array.
    print_leaving($before);
}
continue
{
    if (eof)
    {
        # Print out any accumulated lines that need printing
        print_leaving(0);
        # Reset for next file
        close ARGV;
        $tbp_1 = 0;
        $tbp_2 = 0;
        $tail  = 0;
        @lines = ();
    }
}
```

Comment: @ jonathan : when i used grep -B 10 -A 10 "string pattern" file as a command it worked but when i put this into script it is taking "string as a different string and pattern" as a different (tried using single quotes as well)...what to do now

Comment: There seems to be something very odd about your setup.  You should be able to use what you type at the command line in a script verbatim.  You've not answered my questions about which shell you're using, but in many ways, it shouldn't matter.  What you're showing is basic shell scripting that should work the same everywhere, even in sea-shells (I mean, C shell derivatives).  What is your environment?  Which variant of Unix?  Which shell — again!

Comment: variant of unix is Linux servername 2.6.18-128.el5 #1 SMP Wed Dec 17 11:41:38 EST 2008 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux                                                   environment is /bin/bash and shell is ksh.

Comment: Using grep is the right answer, +1

Answer (score 1):

I bet you're trying to execute your script as `nawk -f file` instead of just `./file`.

Comment: Then do `cat -v file; ./file` and copy/paste the results into your original post so we can see what's really in "file" so we can help you.

Comment: What does what you just posted have to do with your nawk command?

Comment: #!/bin/ksh

Stringname=$1

directory=$2

d=$3

Command="nawk 'c-- >0;$0~s{if(b)for(c=b+1;c >1;c--)print r[(NR-c+1)%b];print;c=a}b{r[NR%b]=$0}' b=10 a=10 s=\"$stringname\" $directory"

$Command> $d

Comment: i am sorry for the above post....this is waht i was trying with nawk.

Comment: I had asked you to copy/paste into your original post since you can't see formatting in comments, and I had asked you to additionally post the output of running the script. Please do that. Also, why do you need your awk script to be stored in a variable? That's your problem.

Comment: this the output when i am running the above scrip,just added that command into variable there is no specific reason               nawk: syntax error at source line 1
 context is
         >>> ' <<<
nawk: bailing out at source line 1

Comment: Since you're unwilling to do what I asked you to do or answer the question I asked, the best answer I can give you is: do not store your awk script in a variable and you will not have the problem you are currently having.

Comment: I've updated the question with the script embedded in the comment.  I've also included the solution in the updated question.  Neither you, Ed, nor I stood a chance of resolving the problem because you, Aditya, were not telling us the crucial information.  The solution is trivial once we have the information we've been requesting.

Comment: i have given all information,can u pls tell me what exactly you want ? i removed that variable and tried as a normal command but still error is same

Comment: All we wanted was for you to answer the questions we asked such as "why do you need your awk script to be stored in a variable?" and to copy/paste your script plus output into your original post, as done now by @JonathanLeffler. As Jonathan says, once we had the information we were asking for, the solution is trivial UNLESS your answer to the remaining question of "why?" is a good one!

Comment: Aditya: (1) Did I put the correct interpretation of the script from the comment into the question?  If not, please fix the question (you can always edit your own question or answer). Assuming that (1) is 'yes; that was it', then you say that the proposed fix still produces the same error. I'm not convinced, but you can demonstrate to us that you're correct by running `ksh -vx fixed-script "string.pattern" directory logfile` (you supply the three arguments you're using to test). That should both echo the script as it is read and the interpretation of it. Include all the output in the question.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler : yes you put the correct interpreteation and yes your suggestion worked for me ,my script is running fine now. apologies for replying late.thanx a lot for your valuable time.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler : one thing i wanted to know is why we should not store command in string, just asking the reason because i am a newbie in unix.

Comment: Basically because, as you demonstrated, it is hard to store a script so that it can be executed properly. Doubly so when the string has to contain single quotes, double quotes, dollars, I/O redirections, pipes or backslashes. The `eval` mechanism might be usable: `eval $Command > $d`. But knowing whether it is going to work with a script like an awk script is hard. If I spent long enough on it, I could work it out — probably. But life's too short, though. I wouldn't do it with most of my stuff; I don't recommend it for you. I have scripts that use `eval`; they are not the most readable ones.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler : understood.